# Should I clear a Set containing millions of data after using it?

Tags: javascript

```
function doSomething(fruitsA: string[], fruitsB: string[]) {
    
  const fruits = new Set(fruitsA.concat(fruitsB))

  const myRottenFrutis = rottenFruits.filter((fruit) => fruits.has(fruit))

  // fruits.clear() 

  // ...

  // ...

  // ...

  // ...


}
```

Now after getting `myRottenFruits`. **I no longer need** `fruits`. The function doesn't end after getting `myRottenFrutis`. And also `fruitsA` and `fruitsB` contains millions of data. So I'm worried if I should clear `fruits` (`fruits.clear()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `doSomething` is synchronous - which it appears to be - then no, clearing the set won't help.

The situation in which clearing the set might help if the set would otherwise remain accessible to the code for a number of seconds after it stops processing. The garbage collector usually runs a bit after when the synchronous JavaScript has finished executing. (It will not run *while* the synchronous JavaScript is still executing.)

Since `doSomething` is synchronous, once that function ends, as long as the Set isn't used elsewhere (like being returned), `fruits` will not be accessible to anything else - resulting in the [engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) automatically garbage collecting it some time after things go idle. So, in that situation, whether or not you do `fruits.clear()` wouldn't matter because the garbage collector won't run until after the function ends anyway, and because the garbage collector will be able to see that `fruits` isn't referenced anywhere else after the function ends.

An example snippet in which clearing the set *could* help:

```
async function doSomething(fruitsA: string[], fruitsB: string[]) { 
  const fruits = new Set(fruitsA.concat(fruitsB))
  const myRottenFrutis = rottenFruits.filter((fruit) => fruits.has(fruit))
  fruits.clear() 
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 20_000));
  // more code here
}
```

If script execution essentially pauses while waiting for the timeout, there's idle time during which the garbage collector might kick in. (But it's not guaranteed.)

That said, such a massive data comparison is somewhat odd to do in JavaScript, rather than in, for example, SQL of a database, which is more optimized to processing large amounts of data.